# intent.getStringExtra not working in android

Tags: android

I'm getting a null value returned from getStringExtra at 1 of 3 occurrences. I see the value is present in the debugger with the correct key.

This is how I'm setting my extras:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("citySearch", city.getText());
intent.putExtra("nDays", nDays.getSelectedItem().toString());
intent.putExtra("method", method.getSelectedItem().toString());
SettingsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And this is where I'm asking it back

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String search = intent.getStringExtra("citySearch") == null ? "Maribor" : intent.getStringExtra("citySearch");
String nDays = intent.getStringExtra("nDays") == null ? "5" : intent.getStringExtra("nDays");
String method = intent.getStringExtra("method") == null ? "json" : intent.getStringExtra("method");
```

It's working for the "nDays" and the "method" but somehow not for the "citySearch". The value is always "Maribor", but I've debugged it and the value returned from the `.getStringExtra()` is null.

Comment: city is a textview? If yes, try using city.getText().toString(), otherwise please tell what it is or post some code from where is the info coming.

Comment: It's an EditView. And yes, the "toString()" solved my problems. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i.putExtra("citySearch", city.getText().toString());
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `city.getText()` to `city.getText().toString()`.
Hopefully it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change `i.putExtra("citySearch", city.getText());` to `i.putExtra("citySearch", city.getText().toString());`